# Why does deploying to one app pool affect CPU usage of other?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

This is not an issue but I am asking out of curiosity as I didn't expect this behavior.

On the server, I have two copies of the web app. One copy at location dir1 is used mainly for testing and debugging purposes. The other at dir2 is the production site.

Earlier, both were using the same app pool. I changed it so that now the test one uses an app pool called testAppPool while the other uses DefaultAppPool.

Now, whenever I deploy a new build to test, the cpu usage of the w3wp.exe process of the DefaultAppPool also goes up. Why does this happen? Aren't they different processes and not be affected by changes in other?

Comment: is is the test dir a child dir of the production dir?

Comment: no, in fact they are on different drives.

Comment: no, they are under different virtual directories.

Comment: I believe that the DefaultAppPool gets restarted. One of the reasons is that many files get's changed.

Comment: Can you check if the application pool is restarted?

Comment: No, the app pool is not restarted. e.g. DefaultAppPool has memory usage of around 800,000K once at steady state. This does not change, but cpu goes up, remains up for a while alongwith test app pool(which gets recycled as expected) and then returns back to normal.

Comment: How many CPU's does your box have? Are you sure that there isn't a call in one app to the other?

Comment: Box has 2 cpu's. But how does that make a difference? Why would CPU usage of other worker process go up and not other processes? Call from one app to other, well I am not to sure what you mean by that. As I said, both are essentially the same code.

Comment: If the CPU is hyperthreaded then the CPUs/cores are not necessarily independent. If one app calls another (i.e. maybe you make a specific request for a resource within the app like a handler or similar, and it's configured to go to www.myapp-live.com rather than www.myapp-test.com, then loading one would also involve loading the other, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, a Virtual Dir in the prod also pointed to the test folder. This I found out today and that seems to be a reason.